# Meteor 1.3+ Accounts Facebook Login for iOS not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have been trying to find a solution (sadly for 3 months now) to login with Facebook using Meteors Accounts Facebook on iOS. I have tried just about everything a Google search will come up with, reached out on the Meteor forums and even opened up a Github issue.

But this problem still escapes me. Everything works fine on desktop but as soon I as I test on mobile I get a Facebook error  *"Not Logged in. You are not logged in. Please login and try again"* .

I have found several others with this issue and very little input on a full proof answer. And at this point I am starting to get desperate.

This wasn't a problem until Meteor went to 1.3 up.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like this is a real problem, as you have found others who have it too. If you are confident enough you could have a look at the Accounts package source code and try to work out the problem, or you could raise a Meteor issue with your evidence (and an example repo). It sounds like this is a problem that needs fixing

Comment: It definitely is, or there just isn't a we'll understood solution. And it's been plaguing me for about 6 months in total.

Comment: Yeah, if you can prompt someone to look at it, I think it's worthwhile

Comment: I left an issue on mdg GitHub about three months ago, then bumped it a month ago. Also got a bump from someone else.

Comment: Send me a link to the issue and I'll bump it too. You know for a while with my builds I was getting a notice something like: "we noticed that you are using OAuth2, which is not supported on IOS..." I figured I'd work that out later, but I haven't seen that recently - I wonder if it was fixed in one of the recent patch updates to 1.4.1.2 - you could try updating and see if it helps

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/accounts/issues/9

Comment: I have the exact same error message on Android on my latest build. I have not changed anything related to facebook on this build compared to the previous. I went to all the issues related to that error message, and you know what ? There should be some indication in the Facebook App Panel of the PRECISE bug, not that shitty error message. Because it can happen in so many cases.....

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me with the following setup

1. Latest version of Meteor and Xcode
2. Account related Meteor Packages

   ```
   accounts-base
   accounts-password
   accounts-facebook
   accounts-google
   useraccounts:materialize 
   service-configuration
   accounts-ui
   splendido:accounts-meld
   ```
3. Rendering the template with

   ```
   {{> atForm}}
   ```
4. I also have 2 cordova plugins added (for that create a file inside `.meteor` folder with the name `cordova-plugins` and the following content

   ```
   cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5
   cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git#2df0e72c36f1fda35c04b3b06bd7beaafaae6ee9
   ```
5. Also make sure you have the following line in your html's head tag

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: " />
   ```
6. Finally add the following lines in your `mobile-config.js` file

   ```
   App.accessRule('http://*', {type: 'navigation'});
   App.accessRule('https://*', {type: 'navigation'});
   ```

Also run a `meteor reset` command before building

Comment: I'll give your process a try this evening.  I am curious though why "meteor reset" is necessary in this case? And would I need to do it before every build?

Comment: Also just curious in the Facebook developers section did you do the standard website platform build?

Comment: I have another question. For cordova-plugins file, what file extension should i use?

Comment: Sometimes the code changed doesn't get reflected in cordova builds (ios and android) and in that case `meteor reset` solves the problem.

Comment: For facebook app creation I followed the instruction shown by the accounts ui (facebook configuration button)

Comment: I actually used a command that I found on some page which created the file (no extension)... you can try the command instead `meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5` and `meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git#2df0e72c36f1fda35c04b3b06bd7beaafaae6ee9
`

Comment: Ok I think I see why. the cordova apps are not installing. because the version string is wrong.

Comment: Ok I got both cordova apps install, but still no luck. still getting the screen above.

Comment: During app creation at developer.facebook.com you need to provide app domain which I'm sure you did. However, also make sure you build your meteor app using the same domain. Something like `meteor build ../output_dir --server http://example.com:3000` (assuming example.com is used while creating fb app... localhost may not work in this case)

Comment: So I may not be doing it right, but I did the following: 
1. Ran the meteor build
2. Open the output folder in Xcode
3. Ran it on a simulator

Which everything worked except now the login with facebook button has completely disappeared and is only showing the normal accounts ui login.

Comment: Did you do a meteor reset before the new build?

Comment: Also if you build the app with `--server http://example.com:3000` remember to run the server with the same domain `meteor run -p http://example.com:3000`

Comment: I am giving it another try right now. After the build xcode prompts me to convert the build to swift 3(recommended) or swift 2.3 . I have tried swift 3 so far and the build failed.

Comment: Swift 2.3 conversion also had a build fail.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to throw up a git repo, that I could pull from?

Comment: This is a demo app `https://github.com/AfzalH/mychannel` that you can pull.I think the build process is important here. What I did was create fb and google app for the domain meteor1.dev and build the app for meteor1.dev and also point the local ip for meteor1.dev on /etc/hosts file

Comment: Out of the box from the git repo this plugin fails "cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp", going to switch to the updated version.

Comment: I used the version available at that moment. In the meantime both meteor and this plugin released more updates. You may need to use a version that matches your meteor version. Also if the latest meteor have the latest cordova and related fixes for iOS 10 then you may not need this plugin at all. Haven't built that repo in a while. Working on something else now

Comment: Yea, I don't know what else to try. I've exhausted all available plugins and techniques. I feel like one of the last few things to try is do it outside Meteor on a standalone Cordova build.

Comment: Maybe you can use React Native for mobile development part. There's a library for connecting it to Meteor. This article may help https://medium.com/differential/connecting-react-native-and-meteor-cccdb0df29e3#.c8wnq3gqq

Answer (score 0):

Here might be the problem in the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7772)

> According to the [author](https://github.com/lorensr)-  **It appears that WKWebView in iOS 10 no longer applies the Meteor Cordova CSP (default-src *) to websockets, and blocks the connection, with the below message. This breaks production apps that make websocket connections** *(perhaps only connections other than the default connection to the Meteor server? not sure)* when their users **update to iOS 10** (which has been released).

The issue lies in the **codeline**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

You can try to replace it by

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' wss://*.ourdomain.tld ">
```

in the file https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/boilerplate-generator/boilerplate_web.cordova.html

and then update the Meteor 1.4 by running `meteor update boilerplate-generator`

You can also try updating `meteor update --release 1.4.2-beta.4` as mentioned in the link that

> This package is run during the build process and updating this package on a project level would not change what files are used to build the app.

Also if it still doesnt work then as suggested by this [author](https://github.com/cunneen)

You can add a simple plugin `meteor add cordova:meteor-ios10-csp-fix@0.1.0`

Repo is [here](https://github.com/AppWorkshop/meteor-ios10-csp-fix) and the npm page is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-ios10-csp-fix)

Hope this helps.

*Full attribution goes to the github link and the authors mentioned above*

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Maybe I didn't get it, right. But this did not seem to do it.

Comment: did you try with both the beta version and the meteor-ios10-csp-fix@0.1.0 plugin too?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work for me, I upgraded to the latest version of meteor, accounts-facebook, etc.

Next I deployed a web version of the app with working facebook login. Then I tested the web app facebook login. All good once the valid oauth redirect URI are added in your facebook app settings. These should be something like https://example.com

Then I ran in terminal `meteor run ios-device --settings settings.json --mobile-server https://example.com`

My mobile-config.js file also contained as recommended by @Afzal Hossain 

`App.accessRule('http://*', {type: 'navigation'});
App.accessRule('https://*', {type: 'navigation'});`

The app put on my device worked for logging in.

No need for cordova plugins or CSP policy any more as meteor updates have made these unnecessary.

Comment: So just take make sure I am getting your process correct. You had to deploy to a live server first?

And for the --mobile-server did you declare a connection or was that established in the settings.json?

Comment: Correct, for testing I deployed a staging version of the site on linode. I didn't have to do anything special in settings.json that I wouldn't do for a regular deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same issue by specifying correct Url in Facebook App's "Valid OAuth redirect URIs".

Earlier, I had specified
`http://<domainname>/_oauth/facebook?close`

which did not work. After some debugging, I found that the URL should be

`http://<domainname>:<port>/_oauth/facebook?close` (with port number)

So In case of a server running on `http://localhost:3000`, it would be `http://<device ip/external ip>:3000/_oauth/facebook?close`

And, in case you are running app with --server=http://www.domainname.com then it would be `http://www.domainname:80/_oauth/facebook?close` (port 80 for HTTP )

Now, I see the Facebook App login page and can login.

But now I am stuck with closing the InAppBrowser after authentication. Any help in this regard would be great!