# Meteor Social Login - Blank page on oauth2 login using Facebook or Google

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am working on a mobile app using Meteor and Facebook or Google login.

On Android devices it works great.

But on iOS devices I get a blank page after successful authentication.The user has to click on a "Done" button to close the page and get the app regain control.

[image: Screenshot of "Done" button to be clicked on]

Meteor version `1.3.4.4` and latest `accounts-facebook`, `accounts-google` packages.

This is the code I am using for login:

```js
//Oauth login with Facebook.
this.loginFB = function() {
  Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
   requestPermissions: ['email', 'public_profile'],
   redirectUrl: Meteor.absoluteUrl('_oauth/facebook')
  }, function(err){
    if( err.error === 'Email exists.' ) {
      if (Meteor.isCordova) {

      } else {

      }
    }
  });
};

//Oauth login with Google.
this.loginGoogle = function() {
  Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
    requestPermissions: ['email', 'profile'],
    redirectUrl: Meteor.absoluteUrl('_oauth/google')
  }, function(err){
    if( err.error === 'Email exists.' ) {
      if (Meteor.isCordova) {

      } else {

      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This might be relevant to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936777/meteor-1-3-accounts-facebook-login-for-ios-not-working?noredirect=1#comment67179180_39936777

Answer (score 0):

I find solution of this bug wery long time, but i found this staff....
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@https://github.com/ephemer/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git#04091fde737519c149e7ad6316971cb6b490c5b3 and it helps me, and i think it helps you =)

Comment: I'd recommend to write in more detail how you managed to fix the issue.

Comment: $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit', function(e, event){
      if ( Meteor.loggingIn() === false ) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }
    });

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
      viewData.enableBack = false;
    });

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function (e, event) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

Answer (score 0):

When creating your iOS hybrid app using Meteor, the latter uses Cordova and the Cordova plugin [InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/).

That plugin is used when presenting the 3rd party OAuth service (whether Facebook, Google, GitHub or whatever), very probably so that the new page does not have access to the local app Cordova API.

**Unfortunately, there was a "bug" in that plugin when used in such a configuration, see [[CB-11136]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11136):**

> InAppBrowser fails to close with WKWebView OAuth
>
> Launching InAppBrowser from Cordova iOS Platform 4+ with its WKWebView for OAuth (e.g. Facebook or Google login) fails to close as it should.
>
> The reason is that the entire WKWebView thread seems to pause when another view controller is presented. This can be confirmed by inspecting the WKWebView session in Safari, running `window.open('http://something.com')` and then trying to enter another command into that Safari console.

This entirely explains why the underlying app cannot take control back and close that new window, but everything works fine when user manually presses the "DONE" button (in particular, access tokens are correctly retrieved and user gets logged in into the app).

This has been fixed as of plugin version [`1.7.0`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md#170-feb-28-2017).

Manually upgrading the InAppBrowser plugin version to `1.7.0` or later fixes the issue on iOS Cordova packaged apps for all tested OAuth login services:

**`meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.7.1`**

(You can browse to the [Cordova Plugins registry](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) to find the latest available release)